# Angularjs and Php Error: Undefined Property stdClass::$passw

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am new to angularjs and I encountered some problem during saving a record to my database. It says in my php that `Undefined property stdClass::$passw`. Here's my code:

```
    $scope.get_admin = function(){

    $http.get('query?action=nimdateg', {})
    .then(function(response){

            $scope.name = response.data.split(',')[0];
            $scope.uname = response.data.split(',')[1]; 

    })
    .catch(function(response){

        $scope.showToast('Failed to retrieve admin data: ' + response.data);
    });

};

 $scope.get_admin();

$scope.account_update = function(isValid){
    if(isValid){

        $http.post('query?action=tnoucca_etadpu',{
            'name': $scope.name,
            'username': $scope.uname,
            'passw': $scope.passw
        })
        .then(function(response){

            alert(response.data); //says "undefined property stdClass::$passw"

        })
        .catch(function(response){
            $scope.showToast("SYS_ERROR: " + response.data);
        });

    }
};
```

And my php:

```
if ($action == "tnoucca_etadpu") {

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$name = $data->name;
$uname = $data->username;
$pw = $data->passw;



}
```

I think its because of the code from `$scope.get_admin` because I didn't declare the `$scope.passw`

Comment: What is `$scope.passw` and what is `print_r($data)`?

Comment: `$scope.passw` if from my html input text `<input name="passw" ng-model="passw" />`. I already tried `print_r($data)` but it only print the `$name and $uname` not the `$pw`. @DaveChen

Comment: So what does `console.log($scope.passw);` print? Please also show the html including the `<form>`.

Comment: See updated question above sir, @DaveChen